# Is there a quick way to disable/enable all event handlers

Tags: delphi

Typically in my applications, I have a place where I "load up" an in-memory dataset (TClientDataSet or DevEx TdxMemData). Before the load it, I do something like this:

```
CDS1.BeforeUpdate := nil;
CDS1.AfterUpdate := nil;
CDS1.AfterPost := nil;
```

... and so on. Then after the load (eg. LoadData(CDS1))

```
CDS1.BeforeUpdate := CDS1BeforeUpdate;
CDS1.AfterUpdate := CDSAfterUpdate;
CDS1.AfterPost := CDS1AfterPost;
```

It's very tedious, especially because not all event handlers are assiged in every context in every application, and sometimes I miss one that comes back to bite me at runtime.

Wouldn't it be nice if I could just call

```
CDS1.DisableallEventHandlers;
LoadData(CDS1);
CDS1.EnableallEventHandlers; // which were assigned at design-time, that is
```

Comment: You could act upon a boolean flag in your eventhander? Like `if CDS1EventHandlersEnabled then ...`. Then all you need to do is set the flag to false, load the data and reenable the flag...

Comment: Usually I have a flag called isLoading, and in all the event handlers it says `if isloading then EXIT;`

Comment: Sure, why not, it is an acceptable solution, don't you think?

Comment: I was hoping for something more erm... elegant.

Comment: It is basically the same thing. If you want a more elegant solution, you could encapsulate this functionality in a derived class or use a RTTI based solution.

Comment: No, there's no such thing

Comment: Why do you disable these event before the load? they wont fire in the loading process.

Comment: That's desired affect. For an in-memory dataset, the loading process must prevent the usual eg BeforePost, AfterPost event handlers that fire during user-editing, from firing.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating a class helper with the methods `DisableallEventHandlers` and `EnableallEventHandlers` whereas each method uses RTTI to enumerate over the event handler properties and stores / retrieves the event handler pointers to / from a map.